# Xamarin Android:Load Image from Localpath On RecyclerView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

Xamarin Android Project Was using Data showing in RecyclerView. I refer this article [RecyclerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/) and Run the code sample.And also refer the ImageLoading Component in Xamarin [picasso](https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso). How to image Fetch From Mobile Localpath like `File imgFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CameraAppDemo/myPhoto_2eb3b135-5ad5-4a17-8836-13a9eca6bbb2.jpg")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso chapter `Resource Loading`

This should work according to the documentation. Don't forget to request the external storage access privilege.

```
var imgFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CameraAppDemo/myPhoto_2eb3b135-5ad5-4a17-8836-13a9eca6bbb2.jpg")
Picasso.With(context)
       .Load(imgFile)
       .Into(imageView3);
```

Comment: Error For Loading images in recyclerview in this method!. Any RecyclerView with Picasso samples available ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    File imgFileone = new  File("/sdcard/Images/imageName.jpg");

if(imgFileone.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFileone.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewCheck);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

note: allow permission in mainfestfile  for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE